# How can i solve this problem kindly "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I´m having some issue inserting a new record to this table.

Though can't seem to find the real issue within my code.

```
try
{
    conn = new MySqlConnection(cs.ConnString);
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Depense_Vehicule (Code,Date,Responsable,Source_Cr,Numero_Plaque_Dt,Possession,Chauffeur,Categorie,Type,Libelle,Montant_$,Montant_FC,Taux_Echange,Total_$,Status)" +
            "VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11,@d12,@13,@14,@15)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", Code_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", Date_ADVe_dt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", Responsable_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", Source_ADV_cb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", Numero_Plaque_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d6", Possesion_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d7", Chauffeur_ADV_cb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d8", Categorie_ADV_cb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d9", Type_Payment_ADV_cb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d10", Libelle_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d11", MontantDollars_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d12", MontantFranc_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d13", TauxEchange_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d14", TotalDollars_ADV_txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d15", Status_ADV_cb.Text);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Ajouter");
    Source_ADV_cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    Chauffeur_ADV_cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    Numero_Plaque_ADV_txt.Text = "";
    Possesion_ADV_txt.Text = "";
    Categorie_ADV_cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    Type_Payment_ADV_cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    MontantDollars_ADV_txt.Text = "";
    MontantFranc_ADV_txt.Text = "";
    TotalDollars_ADV_txt.Text = "";
    Status_ADV_cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    Libelle_ADV_txt.Text = "";

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();

}
```

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: Please provide all exception details (as text): http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery instead of cmd.ExecuteReader().
ExecuteReader is for run SQL SELECT command.

I hope this answer is useful for you.